# Render method doesnt display the state value in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, state, render

I am setting state inside a function which I call in componentDidMount(), but I am not accessing the value of state in the render.

How to access the state inside the render method on time?

**state:**

```
  constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            check_for_amount: '',
        };
    }
```

**componentdidmount() :**

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.check_amount_left();
  }
```

**function:**

```
check_amount_left = () => {
    const getSelected = this.props.navigation.state.params;
    var ref = firebase.firestore().collection('discounts').where("rest_id", "==", getSelected.rest_id)

    ref.onSnapshot((querySnapshot => {
        var amount = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data().amount);
        this.setState({
            check_for_amount: amount
        });
    }));
}
```

**Render:**

```
 render() {
    return(
    <View/>
    <Text>
    {this.state.check_for_amount}
    </Text>
    </View>
    )
    }
```

Comment: What is the exact issue that you're facing?

Comment: @AkshitMehra like I said, I can't access the state in the render method. I am setting the state in that function but I cant access it in render

Comment: Are you sure that `this.setState()` is actually updating your state and the value of `amount` is what you expect? Oops, and you self-closed `<View/>`.

Comment: Did you checked the value of amount in the function? Also your first View has a closed tag,  ` <View/>` must be ` <View>`

Comment: @AkshitMehra I used a simple view and text inside for brevity, please dont mind that.

Comment: Add a debug point or a console log after this line `var amount = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data().amount);` and check the value of amount. I think issue is not with the state it is something with the firestore fetching.

Answer (score 0):

You got wrong `()` at `onSnapshot`. Please check below to see it works for you. If not, try to log inside `onSnapshot` to see if it called properly.

```
check_amount_left = () => {
    const getSelected = this.props.navigation.state.params;
    var ref = firebase.firestore().collection('discounts').where("rest_id", "==", getSelected.rest_id)

    ref.onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
        var amount = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data().amount);
        this.setState({
            check_for_amount: amount
        });
    });
}
```